# :nth-child Recipe to select everything but what i hover

Tags: html, css-selectors

it's very simple, but i can't find the right answer searching on google or here in SO. what i need is a recipe that change color to every element of the list but the one i hover with the cursor, so will look like everything else but the element selected it's activated by the hover event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you think you need nth-child, but here you go.

```css
ul:hover li {
  background: lime;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: inherit;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that's just perfect. tbh i followed a course of webdesign and the teacher made us do that with an nth-child recipe that's why i asked for that, but this is exactly what i was looking for. thank you so much.